# Update Flutter state with GetX when the routing changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm using [GetX](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) to manage the state of my Flutter app, and the structure of my pages consists of an `ItemsListPage` that lists some items, and an `ItemDetailsPage` that shows details about an specific item and lets the user change it or delete it.
I'm managing state using [GetX's Reactive state management](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#reactive-state-manager), which means that, in order to update the state of my `ItemsListPage`, I need to update an observable variable `itemsList` that is inside the `ItemsListController`. This variable is updated on the `onInit()` method of the controller, which means that whenever the controller is instantiated the list should be updated with the data fetched from the API.

The controller of the `ItemsListPage` looks like this:

```
class ItemsListController extends GetxController {
  var itemsList = <AppEntity>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    // Fetch items from the API and store them on itemsList:
    getApps();
  }
  //...
}
```

And the controller of the `ItemDetailsPage` is like this:

```
class ItemsDetailsController extends GetxController {
  void deleteItem() async {
    final response = await deleteItem();

    response.fold((failure) {
      // Deal with a failure on the request
    }, (response) {
      if (response.success) {
        // I want to update the state of the list from here   
        Get.toNamed('/main/');
        Get.snackbar('Deleted', 'Item deleted successfully!');
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that when the user changes or deletes an item (on the `ItemDetails` page), he gets redirected to the main page via `Get.toNamed('/main')`, and sees the old version of the list, because the `onInit()` method isn't called again.

Is there a way for me to trigger an action everytime the user is redirected to the `ItemsList` page? This would allow me to fetch the fresh data from the API and update the page. Another solution would be a way of updating the state of the `ItemsListController` from the `ItemDetailsController`, which would be even better, as it would not require another call to the back-end.

Comment: Can you please share code for reference?

Comment: You can try ItemsList[index].clear() for deleting item from the list and it's reflect on your HomePage.. Or you can use Get.offAll(()=> HomePage()) for recall onInit() method. I hope it's help you :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [get_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/get_cli), then you can pretty much generate and use named routes along with your **view**, **controller** and **bindings**. But if in case you are just using the state management without binding, then this problem may occur.

The thing happening in this scenario is, your controller is building one time and then your **onInit** method is called, after that you do some operation on your list like deleting or adding some data, and then when you go to another screen, your controller doesn't get **disposed**(Strange).

You can solve this by using these ways,

1. Whenever you switch to another screen, let's say using `Get.toNamed(route)` or `Get.offNamed(route)` or `Get.off(route)`, what you can do is before navigating to other screen, you can remove the controller form the memory like this,

`Get.delete<ControllerName>();`

In this way, your controller will be again reinstantiated when you open your screen again(Provided that you have put the `Get.put(Controller())` In your widget.

2. If you are using named routes then you can pretty much directly use them, you don't need to do anything in order to work with them. In case you're facing the error even if you have bindings and named routes then you can perform step 1.
3. If you want to minimize the API calls then whenever the user deleted some item from the list, you can delete it locally and update the UI according to it. This way user won't have to see the loaders again and again.

Comment: Got it. So I have two options: (1) I can keep this strange behavior of maintaining the state between the pages and update it when I want it, which has the drawback of keeping a controller on the memory. (2) The other aproach is to close the controller whenever I route out of it's page, which has the drawback of making another request to the API everytime I route back. So I basically have to chose which of the drawbacks I wanna take?
Also, is there a way of keeping only the state of the list (first aproach) and not the whole controller?

Comment: @G.Hruschka , Sure you can save the list data. For that you have to create a class and in that class you have to define the list of data. Then in the controller, you can create an instance of that class. Now, whenever the API is called first time, you can save that data into the list. That way even if you have not internet connection after that, you can display that data into your view file.

Hope it solves your query.